# Unable to finding the option to set docker workspace option when running the docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have installed docker build step plugin in jenkins. Using that plugin trying to compile java application using maven image.

In docker build step options, I am unable to find the option to setup the working directory.

```
docker run -v /usr/src:/work -w /work maven:latest mvn package
```

Above command works fine while running via shell.

Same logic trying to achive using jenkins docker build step plugin. I can see bind the volume, but can't see the working directory option. Anyone please suggest

Comment: TFS docker plugin i can see the option to set the working directory.

Comment: you figure it out then? feel free to document the answer and accept it if so.

Answer (score 0):

Would an option be to use the `-onbuild` Maven image variant? It has `WORKDIR` set in the `Dockerfile`: https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/ecf54b9839caed8aa2bcf9b8f7bb19594634ee89/jdk-8/onbuild/Dockerfile. In this case you would just mount `/usr/src:/usr/src/app` instead of `/work`.

If the default `mvn install` doesn't work for you (`mvn install` should includ the `package` goal) you could always build your own base image that included a custom `WORKDIR`.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for your comments. But I'm not using any docker file instead of directly running the docker run command on Jenkins docker build step plugin(Using Execute Docker command -> create container build step in jenkins), In the plugin can see the option for mount the volume but no option to set working directory via plugin

Comment: You can still use the onbuild image as it has `WORKDIR` set. It should just ignore the `ONBUILD` steps in that case.